# Create a no break cline

Tags: pdftex, longtable, page-breaking, cline, hline

I have a LaTeX longtable with joined cells and thus with a cline.

The longtable is automatically generated so I cannot manually insert commands because it would be too much work.

I don't want the table to break over a joined cell (see screenshot attached). Data of joined cells should always be on the same page.

[image: unwanted breaking behaviour]

I achieved a similiar behaviour for "hline" by creating a "nobreakhline" and using it in the places I don't want to break.

```
\def\nobreakhline{%
\multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
\noalign{\penalty10000}}
```

I want to copy this behaviour for my clines but I am not enough a LaTeX expert to know how to achieve this.

I hope someone can help me out, if there are further questions I am happy to provide more information :)

Thanks in advance!
Paul

Comment: you should just be able to use `\nopagebreak` after the last cline in  row

Comment: okay i will try that, is there a way to break a custom command for this like i did for hline?

Comment: it does not work like you proposed, the table keeps breaking in the exact same spot...

Comment: ah so it will, you should really have provided an example but I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a penalty in `\cline` it would do no harm in a normal tabular, where page breaking can not occur anyway.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
           %^^^^^^^^
\makeatother
```